# Doubly-true dissections: Dissecting an $n$-gon into $s_i$-gons, such that $n = \sum s_i$

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, dissection

Dissecting a polygon into other ones is a famous subject. Many people have studied varying topics about dissection.

It is well known that a regular hexagon can be dissected into two equilateral triangles. We can denote this dissection by {3}+{3}={6} by using Schläfli symbols.

We can also dissect a regular octagon into two squares and denote it by {4}+{4}={8}.

The equalities {3}+{3}={6} and {4}+{4}={8} also holds as numbers. If an $n$-gon can be dissected into $s_1$-gon, $s_2$-gon, ..., $s_k$-gon and $n = \sum_{i=1}^k s_i$, then I would like to call this type of dissections ''doubly-true dissections.''

For one more example, we can consider {12} = {4}+{4}+{4}.

Do you have any other doubly-true dissection?

[image]

Comment: By the Wallace-Bolyai-Gerwien theorem (see wikipedia), this should be possible for any $n = \sum s_i$ (where all $s_i \geq 3$), right?

Comment: Yes. In principle, every dissection problem can be solved in the finite steps by the WBG theorem. So, the dissection problem needs the small number of pieces as possible.

Comment: This definitely falls in the category of "An answer would fill a book".

Comment: @PeterTaylor haha. Well. I just suggest a new(?) genre of dissection problems. Anyway, I would change my question: “Do you know any book or document about this kind of dissection?”